# Android X86 – No Mouse Cursor in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, virtualbox, setup-wizard

I have recently installed **AndroidX86** ([android-x86_64-6.0-r1.iso](https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/downloads/65890/android-x86_64-6.0-r1.iso/)) in **VirtualBox 5.1.12 r112440 (Qt5.6.2)** following [these instructions](https://www.file-extensions.org/article/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox).

But I see no mouse cursor on the screen. Do I need to set some special preference?

Answer (score 10):

The solution is change **Pointing Device** type to **PS/2 Mouse**:

1. Make sure the VM is not running (powered off)
2. Click on the VM name in the list (e.g., Android X86)
3. Click Settings
4. Click on the System category
5. Make sure you’re on the Motherboard tab
6. Change Pointing Device to PS/2 Mouse

Detailed instructions are here: [Android X86 – No Mouse Cursor in Oracle VirtualBox](http://www.driscocity.com/android-x86-no-mouse-cursor-oracle-virtualbox/).

Comment: I did same and it worked!

But when I switched guest to Host (alt+ctrl+arrow)  and then again switched to guest 
Same mouse pointer issue again ! not able to fix, even selected ps/2 in settings

Comment: @Chandrakant I only saw that issue in the initial Setup Wizard. You can either not switch to host until the wizard is complete, or use a separate USB mouse and assign it as a USB device to the VM.